# NASM one wrong way checking data

Tags: nasm

So, I write a program that creates matrix 4x5 and I have almost done it. I store data in the strings in order to check what information is stored there. When I enter data properly - Ok, but if I make even just one mistake (for example +12asd) then I see my program works again from the "array[3][0]" when I have entered it. What is wrong?

```
; Task: write a program that allows to enter 2-D array 4x5. Show only 2 first columns.



section .bss ; The section intended for uninitilizated data
    string_00 resb 7
    string_01 resb 7
    string_02 resb 7
    string_03 resb 7
    string_04 resb 7

    string_10 resb 7
    string_11 resb 7
    string_12 resb 7
    string_13 resb 7
    string_14 resb 7

    string_20 resb 7
    string_21 resb 7
    string_22 resb 7
    string_23 resb 7
    string_24 resb 7

    string_30 resb 7
    string_31 resb 7
    string_32 resb 7
    string_33 resb 7
    string_34 resb 7

section .data ; The section designed for using initilizated data

    pointer_0 dd string_00, string_01, string_02, string_03, string_04
    pointer_1 dd string_10, string_11, string_12, string_13, string_14
    pointer_2 dd string_20, string_21, string_22, string_23, string_24
    pointer_3 dd string_30, string_31, string_32, string_33, string_34

    pointer dd pointer_0, pointer_1, pointer_2, pointer_3

    external_counter dd 0
    internal_counter dd 0


section .text
    global _start
_start:

    call _check
ex:
    mov ebx, 0
    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80

_print:
    mov ebx, 1
    mov eax, 4
    int 0x80
    ret

_enter:
    mov edx, 7
    mov ebx, 0
    mov eax, 3
    int 0x80
    ret

_make_esi:
    mov eax, [pointer]
    mov ebx, [external_counter]
    mov esi, [eax + ebx * 4]
    mov ebx, [internal_counter]
    add ebx, ebx
    add ebx, ebx
    add ebx, ebx
    add esi, ebx
    ret


_check:
            call _make_esi
            cmp esi, string_01
            je ex
            mov ecx, esi
            call _enter

            inc dword [internal_counter]
            jmp _check
```

Comment: "I see my program works again from the "array[3][0]" when I have entered it."  I don't understand that sentence, and the code is quite long to read.  Can you reduce it to a [mcve], and state the input that you're using, the output you got, and the output you expected?

Comment: Done. When I change esi value to the next string this string01 address is not equal the address of esi. Why?

Comment: Your strings are 7 bytes each, but in `_make_esi` you add `[internal_counter] * 8`